# How to Sign-Out from an authenticated ListDataProvider/Authenticator in Windows Phone 8

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, windows-phone-8, office365, csom

I am reading a SharePoint list from Office 365 inside a Windows Phone 8 app. My app-code is based on this [sample code from Microsoft](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-Store-and-6044b7f0). It uses

- `Microsoft.SharePoint.Phone.Application.ListDataProviderBase`
- `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext`
- `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Authenticator`

The actual problem beeing signout not working!

On the first request to the server, the client asks for authentication and shows a hosted browser window where I can enter my account credentials. I select to stay logged in here.

If i restart the app, it authenticates me without showing the UI again.

I would like to be able to switch user or simply signout leaving no credentials on the phone behind.

I found the following static methods on Authenticator which do not change anything:

```
Authenticator.ClearAllCookies();
Authenticator.ClearAllCredentials();
Authenticator.ClearAllApplicationSettings();
```

What is the prefered way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how I am logging out a user in my SP list App for WP8:

```
        App.MainViewModel.IsInitialized = false;
        Authenticator.ClearAllCredentials();
        App.MainViewModel.Initialize();
        MessageBox.Show("You have been successfully logged out, click refresh to login again.");
```

Your app maybe a little different, but you should at least get to the App and ViewModel to set Initialized as false.  I did expxect the App.MainViewModel.Initialize() to show the login page but need to click refresh after calling this SignOut method to do so, that is why I displayed the messagebox.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: After signout, if the user logins again, is he prompted for his login credentials?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working as expected.

On refresh or sync of the page after the above code has been executed the user is prompted to login again.